# Why my (Firebase) Android application crash on real device but runs perfect in emulated android

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, android-activity, firebase-notifications

Hy guys.

I just wanted to write a simple application, which is start a new Activity when get Notification from Firebase.

The application works well on emulated device (Android 8), but on real devices (LG Leon, Asus Zenpad C) it just stop working when start a new Activity triggered by the notification.

My codes:
AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="hu.bme.tmit.edoorbell">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:screenOrientation= "portrait">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".FirebaseIDService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <activity android:name=".AlertActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package hu.bme.tmit.edoorbell;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "hu.bme.tmit.edoorbell.MESSAGE";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlertActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, "Nem jött semmi.");
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonMain);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

MyFirebaseMessagingService.java

```
package hu.bme.tmit.edoorbell;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "hu.bme.tmit.edoorbell.MESSAGE";
 private static final String TAG = "FCM Service";
 @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // TODO: Handle FCM messages here.
        // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated.
        //Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        String message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        //Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + message);

     Context context = getApplicationContext();
     CharSequence text = message;
     int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

     Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
     toast.show();
        /*Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlertActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
*/
 }
}
```

FirebaseIDService.java

package hu.bme.tmit.edoorbell;

```
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;

public class FirebaseIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

    // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    /**
     * Persist token to third-party servers.
     *
     * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    // Add custom implementation, as needed.
    }
}
```

And last the AlertActivity.java

package hu.bme.tmit.edoorbell;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;


import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;

public class AlertActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alert);

    // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MyFirebaseMessagingService.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(message);
    }
}
```

I don't want anything special function, only that if I send a notification to the phone start the new Activity.

Hope you can help guys, thanks!

Comment: Post the stacktrace ..

Comment: any updates on this?